# Formula to keep list of probabilities to have same ratios and sum to one

Tags: calculus

Suppose I have $N$ probabilities ($N=3$ for easier explanation) that have to always sum up to $1$:

$a=0.2$

$b=0.3$

$c=0.5$

$a+b+c=1$

Now, I want to change the value of $a$ from $0.2$ to $0.1$: how do I calculate the values for the other two probabilities to ensure that their sum will still be $1$ and that the ratios between the remaining probabilities remains unchanged?

What I did was:

$b'+c'=1-a'=0.9$

$b'/c'=b/c=0.3/0.5=0.6$

$c'=0.9/(1+b/c)=0.9/1.6=0.5625$

$b'=0.9-0.5625=0.3375$

Looks good, the ratio and the sum is correct, it's extensible to more probabilities by adding more ratio constraints.

The issue is that I need to do it for a programming project, and I was wondering if there is a mathematical formula that could help me solving this issue with any number of probabilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the $n$ numbers as $\{a_1, a_2, \dots a_n\}$

If $a_1$ changes to $a_1'$, $$\sum_{2}^{n} a_i' = 1 - a_1'$$ and each $a_i$ ($i \in [2, n]$) must be increased proportional to its magnitude to keep the ratio of any two probabilities the same, since if $a_i' := \beta a_i + a_i$ then also the ratio between any two is still $\dfrac{a_i}{a_j}$.

So, $$(1 + \beta) \sum_2^n a_i = 1 - a_1'$$
$$\beta = \dfrac{1 - a_1'}{\sum_2^n a_i } - 1$$

Comment: thanks a lot! My math is a bit rusty, this worked flawlessly! +1 for guiding me to the final result

Comment: @HitLuca no problem, glad to help!

Comment: I just noticed a small issue with your approach. If we assume that $a_0$ and $a_1$ are at $0$, and $a_2$ is at $1$. If we change $a_2$ to, say, $0.8$, then the $\beta$ calculation becomes $n/0$. I solved this by setting $a_0$ and $a_1$ to $(1-0.8) / 2$, but maybe there's an extension of your formula that takes this into account

Comment: @HitLuca yes, well if $\sum _i ^n a_i = 0$ in above equation for $\beta$, then $\beta$ can't be calculated in this case. But in this case, you know that you just need to assign equal value to each $a_i$ other than the one that is changed. So, that's easy to calculate ($a_i = \dfrac{1 - a'}{n - 1}$). Also, keeping "ratio" same does not make much sense with two probabilities that were $0$ since $0/0$ is not defined.